# MailGun through WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use the MailGun extntion by teamsinger in WordPress  ( Civicrm 4.7.11 )

https://github.com/teamsinger/uk.teamsinger.civicrm.mailgun

The main issue I am facing is the webhooks back.

The documentation gives the path 
https://www.example.com/civicrm/mailgun/bounce

Which may well be appropriate for Drupal but not for WordPress.

The code seems to create a page for the hook.

Accessing that page manually

https://www.example.com/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailgun%2Fdrop&reset=1

I can see that it is being reached via

https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailgun%2Fdrop&reset=1

(as it is giving the correct validation failure generated by the code )

The issue is I need MailGun to reach that page and Mailgun is not logged in of course and

https://www.example.com/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailgun%2Fdrop&reset=1

returns with "Sorry, no content matched your criteria."  response

I have turned off all plugins except CiviCRM & turned off permalinks and given "Master control for access to the main CiviCRM backend and API"  to annoymous

All to no avail?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

OK Solved

The URL should be

https://www.example.com/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailgun%2Fdrop&reset=1

AND permalinks must be turned on.

Annoymous access is not required (it seems) for this extension